# How to change Anchor-Style Constraint programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, constraints

I searched so and I even came up with potential solutions. Sadly none of them words.. I am trying to animate the x-Position of a View by increasing the leadingAnchor-Constraint of it.

I create my constraint like this:

```
let margins = self.layoutMarginsGuide
    horizontalConstraint = underline.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.leadingAnchor)
```

And edit the constraints constant like this:

```
func updateUnderlinePosition(offset:CGFloat, pageCount:Int) {

    //Underline just over width of one Screen:
    var underlineOffset = offset / CGFloat(pageCount)

    //Add left margin:
    let margins = self.layoutMarginsGuide
    underlineOffset += 15

    //reposition underlineview
    horizontalConstraint.constant += underlineOffset
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Why do I get error telling my there are conflicting constraints?

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fca2b8c72c0 UIView:0x7fca29d1c830.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x7fca2b8c4970'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fca29c2ccd0 UIView:0x7fca29d1c830.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x7fca2b8c4970'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading + 16.25>"
```

**Edit:**

the Constraints are created like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    //underline.frame = CGRectMake(15, self.frame.height-10, 40, 2)
    underline.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    underline.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    underline.layer.cornerRadius = 1.0
    self.addSubview(underline)
    print(self.backItem)
    let margins = self.layoutMarginsGuide
    horizontalConstraint = underline.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.leadingAnchor)
    let verticalConstraint = underline.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(margins.bottomAnchor)
    let widthConstraint = underline.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(nil, constant: 40)
    let heightConstraint = underline.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(nil, constant: 2)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
}
```

Comment: It looks like you modified the constraint correctly, but that there was a second constraint out there which conflicts with it. Before you call `updateUnderlinePosition`, you should check what constraints are defined for this view and I suspect you'll see multiple leading constraints. In terms of how you ended up with two leading constraints, that's hard to say without seeing how they were created/activated. Perhaps you already had leading constraint before you created `horizontalConstraint` and activated it.

Comment: added the methods for creating the constraints.
horizontalConstraint is a global var to be able to access it later.

Answer (score 0):

Check that layoutSubviews is being called twice

Comment: That was it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding constraints in `layoutSubviews` which can be called multiple times. You're instantiating `underline` once, but can call `layoutSubviews` multiple times, referencing the same instance of `underline`, losing your reference to the original `horizontalConstraint` in the process.

Frankly, the adding of subviews and constraints doesn't really belong in `layoutSubviews`. You should set up the constraints where you instantiate the `underline` view, which you can do in the appropriate view `init` method or in `awakeFromNIB`. It depends upon how the view was instantiated.

Comment: I am creating my View in a Subclass of UINavigationBar. Where would you recommend setting up the view?

Comment: Probably wherever you are instantiating `underline`, likely an `init` method.